# Printing tuple instead of three strings

Tags: python, aptana, aptana3

I am trying to learn python, so I downloaded aptanaStudio3 and *this* happens.

Code:

```
print('One', 'Two', 'Three')
```

Output:

```
('One', 'Two', 'Three')
```

it should print just

```
One Two Three
```

Comment: your current code is printing a tuple of three elements

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded python3?

Comment: You're using Python 3 syntax on Python 2. Get Python 3.

Comment: i mean, thats what it says:

 "Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044
(c) Copyright 2005-2013 by Appcelerator, Inc. All rights reserved."

maybe i should install it again, i dont know

edit: ok nevermind i should be able to find a way to get python3 on aptana. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 has `print` as a command, so all you need is

```
print 'One', 'Two', 'Three'
```

In Python 3, `print` is a function, so the parentheses are required for the call.

In most contexts, the series of values in parentheses is a `tuple`; this is just like a `list`, except that you can't change the individual elements (i.e. a tuple is *immutable*).

Answer (score 2):

`'One', 'Two', 'Three'` is a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm). You need to do `'One' + 'Two' + 'Three'`, or you can just keep it in one string like `One Two Three`, so that you are printing a string.

A tuple is a group of strings, and you just need to print a single string. You probably typed `,` which defines a tuple, instead of `+`, which [concatenates](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) strings. Make sure you are using `print("")` for Python 3, and `print ""` for Python 2.

Read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the python3 style print function in python2, you can use the following:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('One', 'Two', 'Three', sep=' ')
One Two Three
```

The `sep` keyword is the separator used between arguments and defaults to `' '`.

By doing this, you can write `print` related code that will work in both python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
print("{0} {1}".format(var1, var2))
```